# Global "swap characters" macro in KDE

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, macro

After moving from OSX back to KDE I found the thing I'm missing most is the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> global shortcut that flips the characters surrounding the cursor, making it easy to fix typos. The important aspect of it on a Mac is that it's globally available, so it works in all applications, with all input types, in the terminal etc.

Is there a way to replicate this mechanism in KDE? I gave Khotkeys a try but it seems to depend on external commands/scripts to perform the actual action, I suspects this may not cut it.

Answer (score 0):

Start launcher, search for shortcuts

3 items will appear

- global shortcuts
- standard shortcuts
- custom shortcuts

Select Global shortcut and reassign your 
[image]

References:

- https://megalodon.jp/2019-0409-0453-20/https://www.addictivetips.com:443/ubuntu-linux-tips/customize-keyboard-shortcuts-on-kde-plasma-5/
- http://www.webcitation.org/77UIla9PI
- https://archive.li/lW7ru
- https://web.archive.org/web/20190408195546/https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/customize-keyboard-shortcuts-on-kde-plasma-5/

Comment: *"(...) and reassign your"*... What? I know I can change key shortcuts, unless you know a command that swaps characters your answer doesn't help. Also, all your references seem to lead to the same article - why include four dodgy links instead of a single but trustworthy one (or at least one that displays correctly in modern browsers...)

Comment: If you want to swap characters, you must work with keycode and keysym. It is recommended to create a personal file for your custom keycodes. 
https://hyp.is/0oxIdlq_EemIX6t7tA8EdA/wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration

As for the links, they are archives of the original as a measure to fight link rot. Did you know the average web page lives only 100 days?

Comment: Yep, that's why Stack Exchange advises to ["Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Note that *"Select Global shortcut and reassign your"* [sic] or *"you must work with keycode and keysym"* does not *really* answer the original question. The problem is not just a matter of remapping individual keys as it involves a copy-paste operation of the characters around the cursor.